# '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python, django, object

En mi aplicación web sobre Django tengo este código:

```
docPDF = open('publicaciones/Dictamen-'+nombreRevista+'.pdf','rb')
dictamen.fileEsp.save(name=final_name,content= docPDF)
```

Sin embargo, la última línea me da error:

> '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'size'

`final_name` es un String

Comment: ¿Qué valor tiene `final_name`?

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save), tienes que usar [`File`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File) al guardar en un `FileField`. Por lo tanto, lo que tendrías que hacer es:

```
from django.core.files import File

# ...
docPDF = open('publicaciones/Dictamen-'+nombreRevista+'.pdf', 'rb')
dictamen.fileEsp.save(name=final_name, content=File(docPDF))
```

Y como puedes apreciar en la documentación, la clase `Field` sí cuenta con un atributo `size`.